# need help while tesing println and fmt.println of golang

Tags: go, println, gofmt

I wrote simple codes to test println and fmt.Println, but when I ran the code, it printed different results almost everytime. I tried to google the difference between println and fmt.Println but got nothing. Is there any one who knows the real difference or the priority or the sequence of those two function?

Here is the code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    println("a")
    fmt.Println("b")
    println("c")
    fmt.Println("d")

    p()
}

func p(){
    println("e")
    fmt.Println("f")
    println("g")
    fmt.Println("h")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you interested in using `println()`? This is not a formal part of the language spec and can disappear in the future. See: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after `println("a")`

Comment: @koljanep: The semicolon is not relevant to the question: [Semicolons](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Builtin functions](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/)
>
> [func println](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println)
>
> ```
> func println(args ...Type)
> ```
>
> The println built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation- specific way and writes the result to standard error.
>   Spaces are always added between arguments and a newline is appended.
>   Println is useful for bootstrapping and debugging; it is not
>   guaranteed to stay in the language.
>
> [Package fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> [func Println](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println)
>
> `func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`
>
> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes
>   to standard output. Spaces are always added between operands and a
>   newline is appended. It returns the number of bytes written and any
>   write error encountered.

`fmt.Println()` uses `stdout`; `println()` uses `stderr`.

As expected, two different functions with different purposes give different results.

Comment: To add color to this, standard error and standard out are two different output streams.  There is no guarantee as to the order they are displayed to your terminal.  If you chants fmt.Println to fmt.Fprintln(os.StdErr,"b") then they will interleve as you expect

Comment: This comment is the important part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice: only use `fmt.Println("My text...")`

Do not use `println("My text...")`